# Extreme novice needs help with quick launch. (foundation 2010)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, quick-launch

Hope someone can help. I've been 'playing' around with sharepoint and i'm trying to set it up as a kind of company intranet.

I downloaded the greenshades theme (the custom foundation one from riolinx) and its exacly what I want.

However, the quick launch doesn't seem to work, I can see the place holder using SP designer and the code to my untrained eye looks ok.

Any ideas how I can get it back?

I'm not a coder generally so this is a bit out of my comfort zone so any help appreciated. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "the quick launch doesn't seem to work" ? Is not there, links are not working, not showing all the links that were there before applying the theme? (Just wild guesses). And also please, what do you mean by "how I can get it back"? Please edit your question, include more details, so we can understand better your problem on the first read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that design, but chances are the element is hidden via CSS. Using the IE Dev toolbar (press F12 to load) you can explore the page. Alternatively, you can just right click and select view source.

Search for the class ms-quickLaunch. This should list your navigation that you're missing. Confirm it's there at all.

If it isn't, then their master page did some other funky stuff. I'd have to get a closer look.

If it is there, then looking in the F12 dev toolbar, you can see what the display properties are of the class. See screen shot http://screencast.com/t/xKFAvIn37g. Select the item on the left to see it's properties on the right. If you see display:none on the right, then you can see what file is setting this property, in my example it's all corev4.css.

Sorry if this was confusing, might be too much to jam into a reply. Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: Thanks David, I'm just popping out of the office now, but i'll investigate upon my return. Many thanks for the reply!

Comment: Just had a quick look before I leave, seems that ms-quicklaunch isn't present.

Comment: Looks like the master page is hiding it. In SharePoint Designer, you should see something like http://screencast.com/t/VjAuDzsu in the master page. Line numbers will differ as their master page will have different content in it.

Comment: I downloaded the same masterpage and it appears that they removed the quicklaunch all together. It'll take some customizing to jam it back in there and have the design still work, considering the HTML and CSS layouts.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like a lost cause then. Well thank you for checking it out, much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to contact the company and ask them for a revised company, or find a SP freelancer to mod it for you. Shouldn't be a huge fix.

Comment: Also, if this question is considered answered, please mark it answered for the benefit of the community. ;)